# JavaFX Transition Equivalent

Tags: java, javafx, transition, equivalent, interpolation

I have a non-gui application where I want to asynchronously interpolate some data over time.

I had a look at the JavaFX Transition API and it looked ideal. However, for the transitions API to work it has to be run as part of a JavaFX application context - which I don't really want to add the overhead unnecessarily for.

I was wondering if anyone could suggest something equivalent? Or is this something I'm going to have to write myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `java.util.Timer` for that. You can give it a `TimerTask` (basically a `Runnable`) that it will execute every x ms (its period). It also runs on a background thread, which I assume is what you meant with asynchronously?

API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: I was hoping not to have to write my own manager but I can't find any pre-made solutions so this is probably my best bet

Comment: I forgot to mention in original post that I wanted to use some of the JavaFX interpolation features, which is where the complexity comes from in writing my own version using Timers.

Comment: If you're using JavaFX animations/timelines, they use JavaFX's "pulse" to run, which is explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1106308